# Realm : Store JsonArray as String field of CustomObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an object like above one, but instead of String array, it is like jsonArray. I want to store that as a string to the realm. Have a look at below JSON structure for same.

```
{
  "id": "aadessddsdss9bdfs69c-6f13-4417-b356-230dbb36c887",
  "propertyId": "49bbe89e-8709-4e0f-a680-3c73aa36e424",
  "rowId": "zzzadsaaedsd3fsdfsss33a-11fc-4396-8c69-d88001e813c5",
  "jobFormsId": "",
  "observation": [
    {
      "FieldId": "ddbaesds33fsdf13a-11fc-4396-8c69-d88001e813c5",
      "Value": "sfshello"
    },
    {
      "FieldId": "e88dddfssdc4s7c4-73bc-45ba-900f-bf5286036003",
      "Value": "ritika"
    },
    {
      "FieldId": "b2ea8sdsdsfssdc144-812d-47a2-9239-8471558df189",
      "Value": "May"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have made Class to store above json structure to realm (Here I want to store observations as String to realm)

**AdditionalData.java**

```
public class AdditionalData extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String jobFormId;
    private String propertyId;
    private String observations;
    private String rowId;

    public AdditionalData() {
        // Empty constructor
    }
}
```

Now, When am **storing observations as a string** to realm the format of that is getting changed. What is the proper way to store **observations as a string** to the realm.

**Update:**
I know that, to store observations, I need to make separate class for that. But the data in Observations can be anything. That's why I want to store that as String only.

Comment: So what is the question? If you want to store `observations` as a string, you just need to do it manually.

Comment: @beeender manually means?

Comment: I tried possible ways to store that as String but I can't able to do that.

Comment: `String str = jsonObject.getJSONArray("observation").toString(); additionalData.setObservations(str);` does this help?

Comment: Yes, this stored the data but when I retrieve, it is having escape parameters in observation.